# Acquiring thread id (tid) in glib

Tags: glib

I am using glib for creating threads:

```
g_thread_create()
```

How can I acquire thread id (number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The thread ID is abstracted away in GLib. What do you need it for?

Comment: For debug purposes. I wanted to print tid in error_log with error message.

Comment: If you want a unique symbol for each thread, you can `printf("%p\n", g_thread_self());` This will give you the address of the `GThread` structure, so you can tell your threads apart.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vala, you can use :

```
   var t = Thread.self<bool> () ;
   message ("OTHER THREAD: %p", t) ;
```

The output is:

```
** Message: vala-thread.vala:6: OTHER THREAD: 0x165e400
```